# How do you get to New Game + in Fez?

Tags: fez

I'm currently at about 180% of the game completion but I can't get to the end kill screen. I've got 2 or 3 of those pink cubes, mostly found thanks to help on the internet. However, I don't know how to actually get to the "end" and get the new glasses/first person vision for New Game +. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

To finish the game, go through the 32-cube door and enter the portal for the endgame sequence. When it's over, your only other option for restarting the game will be the New Game+. In the sequence where Gomez first receives the fez, he will instead receive "deal with it" glasses that will allow you to look around in first person view.

So you'll want 32 of the 64 regular and anti-cubes. The pink heart pieces don't count.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 new game +. To get the sunglasses, use only 32 cubes. For Flying and 3D mode, use 64.